# Why isn't HTTPFound redirecting the page

Tags: python, backbone.js, pyramid

I've got a Backbone application that doesn't redirect after a `save`. I don't know if this is something to do with Backbone or the server side code.

On the server:

```
url = request.route_url('test')
return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

I can see that `location` is correctly set to `/test` in the response headers. And following that there is a request with 200 OK to `/test` yet the page is not redirected.

Comment: How are you redirecting after save? Backbone does not do any redirection by default.

Comment: HTTP(location=url) is what should redirect the page.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Backbone is going to make a save request ajaxically. So if you are returning HTTPFound response to a ``Backbone.save`` that isn't going to do anything. If you will need to do the redirection on the client side (given a successful save) or pass things over to the server.

Comment: Shouldn't an HTTP 302 response redirect the page regardless of ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are saving by using an AJAX request (Backbone `save` documentation here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) the client will not be redirected by the server response.  This is not just because of Backbone, this is the nature of AJAX requests. If you want to redirect after a successful save you need to do that manually by setting a callback in the `success` option of the `save`. The `success` callback will given three arguments, model, response, and options (in that order), so you can use the response from the server to redirect.

In your server, you should respond to a successful save with the saved model rendered as a JSON object. What I did to then redirect the page was I added the target location to the location attribute of the response header. You can get the `xhr` attribute from the `options` object in the success callback, and call `getResponseHeader('location')` on it to get the location and then direct the `window` there:

```
model.save({}, {
  success: function(model, response, options){
    window.location = options.xhr.getResponseHeader('location');
  })
});
```

I'm not too familiar with Pyramid, so if someone wants to edit this answer with the best way to return a JSON object and modify the response location header in the server please do. [According to these docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/renderers.html#serializing-custom-objects) and [these docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#pyramid.response.Response.location), it should look something like this:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __json__(self, request):
        return {'x':self.x}

@view_config(renderer='json')
def object(request):
    request.response.location = "http://LocationToRedirectTo.com"
    return MyObject(1)

# the JSON value returned by ``object`` will be:
#    {"x": 1}
```

And of course you need to change all that to actually save your object instead of creating the sample `MyObject` object.